# Creating link in dataGrid

Tags: php, xml, apache-flex

```
 <mx:DataGrid visible="false" id="dgPosts" width="365" click="" dataProvider="{sendReq.lastResult.loginsuccess.name}" x="140.5" y="169">
           <mx:columns>
               <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="name" dataField="name"/>
           </mx:columns>
       </mx:DataGrid>
```

When i click on a particular dataItem, the corresponding website must open. I have tried  dgPosts.selectedItem.name but its not working.

I am getting the result as XML....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dpcontrols_7.html) page, create an `itemClick` event handler on your DataGrid. In the function specify as the click handler, get the data you need from the [DataGridEvent](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/events/DataGridEvent.html) event. After you have the url in the format you need, use the [navigateToUrl](http://blog.flexexamples.com/tag/navigatetourl/) function to go to that link.