# Adding a query string to a hyperlink in a asp.net data grid (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, query-string, hyperlink

Hey, I have a hyperlink column. I need to add just one query string to the url. It needs to pass the string located in the first column of the same row. Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks

Edit: Also, if you don't mind it might be useful if I was able to pass the primary key of the object bound to that row, instead of the string in the first column. Would that be tricky to do? Either would work fine.

Comment: check this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925850/creating-link-in-datagrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

I added the code to the databind function for the grid.

```
HyperLink link = (HyperLink)e.Row.Cells[5].Controls[0];
                link.NavigateUrl = "~/viewDocuments.aspx?id=" + current.ID;
```